# I would like to store a URL inside the extendedData to later use it in the description

Tags: kml, quotes, cdata

I am currently creating a KML file which stores all the relevant information in the  fields. This includes two URLs (one to another page, one to the image which should be displayed).

```
<ExtendedData>
<Data name="sProUrl">
    <value>http://bla.com/bla.htm</value>
</Data> 
</extendedData>
```

I am doing this so I can access the data by using $[test] to access all the information in the  tag.

```
<![CDATA[<table><tr><td><b><a href=&quot;$[sProUrl]&quot;>]]>
```

OR

```
<![CDATA[<table><tr><td><b><a href="$[sProUrl]">]]>
```

This works fine with just items that only contain text, but it fails for the web and image link. Somehow the quotes inside the CDATA and the $[] seem to not get along. Meaning that the link is not displayed correctly:

> http://bla.com/bla.htm"" target="_blank">Example Text that should be the link

I tried to escape the character with an \, I tried to put the quotes inside the value and other things, but nothing works.

### Any ideas?

Here's a more complete code example, enjoy:

```
<Style id="style001">
<IconStyle>

    <color>ff7f3d08</color>
    <colorMode>normal</colorMode>

    <Icon>
        <href>http://bla.com/white-dot.png</href>
    </Icon>

    <hotSpot x="0.5"  y="0.0" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/> 

</IconStyle>

<BalloonStyle>
    <text>
        <![CDATA[<a href=&quot;$[sProUrl]&quot;>[sTitle]</a></b><table style="width:100%;padding:0px;margin:0px"><tr><td valign="top"><i>$[sPrize]</i><br><b>Year:</b> $[iYear]<br><b>Author:</b> $[sAuthor]<td align="right"><img src="$[sImgUrl]"></td></tr></table>]]>
    </text>
</BalloonStyle>
```

```
<Placemark>
<description />

<styleUrl>#style001</styleUrl>

<Point>
    <coordinates>-4.2437307340134,31.438844258775,0</coordinates>
</Point>

<ExtendedData>
    <Data name="sProUrl">
        <value>http://bla.com/bla.htm</value>
    </Data>

    <Data name="sTitle">
        <value>Title</value>
    </Data>

    <Data name="sPrize">
        <value>Prize</value>
    </Data>         

    <Data name="iYear">
        <value>2013</value>
    </Data>     

    <Data name="sAuthor">
        <value>mebu83</value>
    </Data> 

    <Data name="sImgUrl">
        <value>http://bla.com/bla.jpg</value>
    </Data>
</ExtendedData>
</Placemark
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can post more information it would help, but the first thing I note is the escaped quotes in the CDATA section which is also not properly terminated. e.g. could it not be:

```
<![CDATA[<table><tr><td><b><a href="$[sProUrl]"]]>
```

Secondly, with more of you code the intent of what you are doing there might be clearer (and allow for a better answer).